# Not responsive divs using bootstrap, they only looks fineonly in pc and smartphone screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing a problem, I'm trying to put five logos inside divs in the home of a Website using bootstrap, but for some reason when I resize the screen , in a certain point they become a total mess. ¿Can anyone bring me some light in how can I solve this issue? Many Thanks.
Here is the HTML and CSS code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cybertrust - Inspirando Confianza</title>

    <meta content="all" name="robots"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Gobernabilidad, Auditoría y Gestión de Fraude, Integridad de Aplicaciones, CyberSeguridad, CyberAcademia, Crisis Management y Resiliencia, capacitación, Gobiernos Corporativos, Auditoría Interna, Integridad de Aplicaciones ERP, Cyber Seguridad, Gestión de Crisis, Viridis, GlobalSecure, Mindfield">
    <meta name="author" content="Cybertrust">
    <meta name="description" content="Ofrecemos servicios multidisciplinarios de Gobernabilidad, Auditoría y Gestión de Fraude, Cyber Seguridad">
    <meta name="Revisit-after" content="10 days">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ct-skin.css">
</head>

<body class="home wow fadeIn">
    <nav style="position: fixed;width:100%;z-index:99">
        <h1 class="brand pull-left">Cybertrust</h1>
        <div href="#" id="trigger-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        <div id="menu-mobile">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="acerca-de-cybertrust.html">Nuestra Empresa</a>
                    <a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">Servicios</a>
                    <a href="academia-calendario-cursos.html">Calendario</a>
                    <a href="contactenos.html">Contáctenos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <li><a href="acerca-de-cybertrust.html" id="empresa">Nuestra Empresa</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="acerca-de-cybertrust.html">Acerca de Cybertrust</a></li>
                    <li><a href="valores-cybertrust.html">Valores</a></li>
                    <li><a href="socios.html">Socios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">Servicios</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">Governances, Audit & Fraud Management</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="servicios-integridad.html">Application  Integrity</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="servicios-cyberseguridad.html">Information Security & Cybersecurity</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="servicios-cyberacademia.html">Cybertrust Academy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="servicios-crisis.html">Crisis Management, Business Continuity & Resilience</a></li>
                    <li><a style="margin-top: 4%;" href="servicios-cybertrustcenter.html">Cybertrust Center</a></li>

                </ul>                           
            </li>
            <li><a href="academia-calendario-cursos.html">Calendario</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactenos.html">Contáctenos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="container-fluid hero">
        <span class="logo-hero wow fadeInUp hidden-xs"></span>
        <h2 class="bounce wow fadeInUp">INSPIRANDO CONFIANZA EN NUESTRA GENTE, NUESTROS CLIENTES Y EN LOS MERCADOS</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="container-fluid servicios">
        <h2>Nuestros Servicios</h2>
        <h3>Ofrecemos servicios multidisciplinarios en distintos ámbitos</h3>

            <div class="homeLogos">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 servicio-item wow fadeInUp">
                        <a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">
                        <figure class="ico__servicio ico__servicio--gob"></figure>
                        <a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">GOVERNANCES, AUDIT & FRAUD MANAGEMENT</a>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 servicio-item wow fadeInUp">
                        <a href="servicios-cyberseguridad.html">
                        <figure class="ico__servicio ico__servicio--seg"></figure>
                        <a href="servicios-cyberseguridad.html">INFORMATION SECURITY & CYBERSECURITY</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 servicio-item wow fadeInUp">
                        <a href="servicios-integridad.html">
                        <figure class="ico__servicio ico__servicio--int"></figure>
                        <a href="servicios-integridad.html">APPLICATION INTEGRITY</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 servicio-item wow fadeInUp">
                        <a href="servicios-cyberacademia.html">
                        <figure class="ico__servicio ico__servicio--acad"></figure>
                        <a  href="servicios-cyberacademia.html">CYBERTRUST ACADEMY</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 servicio-item wow fadeInUp">
                        <a href="servicios-cybertrustcenter.html">
                        <figure class="ico__servicio ico__servicio--cyb"></figure>
                        <a href="servicios-cybertrustcenter.html">CYBERTRUST CENTER</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div>
                    <a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html" class="btn btn-ver-mas">VER MÁS</a>
                </div>

            </div>

    </section>

    <section class="container-fluid valores">
        <div class="col-md-7 valores-abstract">
            <h2 class="wow fadeIn">Nuestros Valores</h2>
            <h3 class="wow fadeInDown">Queremos ser innovadores y creativos en nuestros servicios y las soluciones que entregamos.</h3>
            <div class="container-btn">
                <a href="valores-cybertrust.html" class="btn btn-ver-mas">VER MÁS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>ç

    <footer class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs">
            <span class="logo-footer"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 copyright">
            <p>&copy; 2016 Cybertrust. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
            <p>Av. Apoquindo 4775, Piso 3 - Las Condes, Santiago de Chile.<br>
            Teléfono: <a href="tel:+56232243551">+562 3224 3551</a> | <a href="tel:+56232243552">+562 3224 3552</a><br>
            Email: <a href="mailto:contacto@cybertrust.cl">contacto@cybertrust.cl</a></p>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/cybertrustcl" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" width=40></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/cybertrustcl" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png" width=40></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cybertrust-spa" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png" width=50></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 footer-sitemap hidden-xs">
            <ul>
                <li class="titulo-seccion">NUESTRA EMPRESA</li>
                <li><a href="acerca-de-cybertrust.html">Acerca de Cybertrust</a></li>
                <li><a href="valores-cybertrust.html">Valores</a></li>
                <li><a href="socios.html">Socios</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="titulo-seccion">SERVICIOS</li>
                <li><a href="servicios-gobernabilidad.html">GOVERNANCES, AUDIT & FRAUD MANAGEMENT</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios-integridad.html">>APPLICATION INTEGRITY</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios-cyberseguridad.html">INFORMATION SECURITY & CYBERSECURITY</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios-cyberacademia.html">CYBERTRUST ACADEMY</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios-crisis.html">CRISIS MANAGEMENT, BUSINESS CONTINUITY & RESILIENCE</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios-cybertrustcenter.html">CYBERTRUST CENTER</a></li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--js-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/menu-home.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>

    <!--GA-->
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-74516113-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700);

*{
    ---outline: 1px solid red;
}

body{
    background: #efe9e9;
    font: 14px "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #555;
}

.down{
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.membersAside{
    position: sticky;
}

.justifiedP{
    text-align: justify;
}

.fluid-container.contenido.academyWidth{
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.centered{
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    text-align: center;
    color: #1b4e96;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-top: 30px;


}
.centered2{
    text-align: center;
    color: #1b4e96;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

.cybertrustSection{
    background: #090909;

}

.cybertrustSection p{

    text-align: justify;
    margin: 50px;
}

.cybertrustSection li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.newAcademyLogo{
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -88%;
    margin-left: 5%!important;
}


.ricardo{
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
}


.container-fluid{

}

.divsMainServicesComplete{
    width: 208px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;

}

.contenidoServices {
    padding-top: 0!important;
}

.divsMainServices{
    width: 208px;
    height: 470px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#4AB1D7;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    position: relative;

}

.whiteStripeText{
    margin:0 auto;

}
.whiteStripe{
width: 100%;
background-color:#efe9e9;
height: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 135px;
}

.whiteStripe.dos{
width: 100%;
background-color:#efe9e9;
height: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
text-align: center
}

.whiteStripe.tres{
width: 100%;
background-color:#efe9e9;
height: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 85%;
}

.whiteStripe.cuatro{
width: 100%;
background-color:#efe9e9;
height: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 90%;
}

.mini-perfil {
    width: 50px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


#trigger-menu {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #28b7e1;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0px solid #28b7e1;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px -5px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#menu-mobile {
    background: #12396f;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: -480px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#menu-mobile ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-mobile a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d4b8d;
}

#menu-mobile.activo {
    right: 0;
}

nav{
    background: rgba(27,68,150,.9);
    background: #24559a;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}

.submenu, .footer-sitemap ul {
    text-transform: none;
}



/*ul:not(.submenu):not(.footer-sitemap ul) > li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}*/

.pull-right > li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav.fixed {
    margin-top:0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
}


nav .brand{
    width: 121px;
    height: 36px;
    color: transparent;
    background:url(../img/home/logo-cybertrust.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

nav ul{
    display: table;
    list-style: none;
    border: none;

}

nav ul li{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    font: 400 14px "Lato";
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #2579b5;
}

nav ul li.active{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #28b7e1;
}

nav ul li:hover a{
    color: #28b7e1;
}

nav ul li a:link,
nav ul li a:visited{
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav ul li a.activo,
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > .submenu{
    display:block
}

nav ul li .submenu{
    background: rgba(27,68,150,.9);
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li > .submenu li{
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 32px;
    outline: 0px solid blue;
}


nav ul li > .submenu li a{
    width: 100%!important;
    display: block;
    outline: 0px solid red;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 32px;
}

nav ul li > .submenu li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 0!important;
}


nav ul li .submenu.up{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
}


/*FOOTER*/

footer{
    background: #51545a;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #a8b3c6;
    font-size: 13px;
}

footer .logo-footer{
    background: url(../img/home/logo-footer.svg) no-repeat center center;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    width: 130px;
}

footer .copyright p{
    font-size: 12px;
}

footer .copyright ul{
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer .copyright ul li{
    line-height: 140%;
}

footer .footer-sitemap{
    display: table;
}

footer .footer-sitemap ul{
    display: table-cell;
}

footer ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

footer .titulo-seccion{
    font-weight: 700;
}

footer .titulo-seccion:after{
    content: "";
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9eb4c9;
    display: block;
}

footer a{
    font: 13px "Lato";
    line-height: 140%;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #a8b3c6;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*TITULOS*/
h2{
    font: 24px "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #7b89a2;
    width: auto;
}

h2:after{
    content: "";
    width: 60px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9eb4c9;
    display: block;
}

h3{
    font: 24px "Lato";
    font-weight: 300;
    border: 1px solid #7b89a2;
    color: #7b89a2;
}

h4{
    font: 700 24px/130% "Montserrat";
    color: #1b4e96;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h5{
    font: 700 16px "Lato";
    color: #647c98;
}

h5 a {
    color: #647c98;
}

.container-btn{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    clear: both;
}

.container-btn2{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

.btn-ver-mas,
.btn-ver-mas:visited{
    color: #7b89a2;
    border-color: #7b89a2;
    font: 12px "Montserrat";
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
}

.btn-ver-mas:hover,
.btn-default:hover{
    color: #1b4e96;
    border-color: #1b4e96;
}

.btn-default{
    background: #436184;
    color: #FFF;
    font: 14px "Montserrat";
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/*HOME*/

.home h3{
    border: none;
}

.hero{
    height: 595px;
    background: url(../img/home/bg-hero.png) no-repeat center center #436184;
    background-size: cover;
}

.hero h2{
    text-align: center;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    color: #fff;
}

.hero h2:before{
    content: "";
    width: 60px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9eb4c9;
    display: block;
}

.hero h2:after{
    display: none;
}

.hero .logo-hero{
    width: 55px;
    height: 90px;
    display: block;
    margin: 150px auto 20px auto;
    background: url(../img/home/iso-cybertrust.svg) no-repeat center center;
}

.servicios,
.valores{
    padding: 60px 0;
}

.servicios{
    background: #f9f7f7;
}

.ico__servicio{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 30px auto 15px auto;
}

.ico__servicio--gob{
    background: url(../img/iconos/iconos-Servicios_WEB-01.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__servicio--seg{
    background: url(../img/iconos/iconos-Servicios_WEB-03.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__servicio--int{
    background: url(../img/iconos/iconos-Servicios_WEB-02.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__servicio--acad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/iconos-Servicios_WEB-06.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;

}

.ico__servicio--cyb{
    background: url(../img/iconos/iconos-Servicios_WEB-07.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;

}

.homeLogos{
    position: relative;
    left: 8%;
}

.servicios h2,
.servicios h3{
    text-align: center;
}

.servicio-item{
    text-align: center;
}

.valores{
    background: url(../img/home/bg-valores.png) no-repeat center left #e5e8ed;
    height: 430px;
}

.valores-abstract{
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.valores-abstract h2:after{
    margin-left: 0; 
}

.valores-abstract .container-btn{
    text-align: left;

}


/*VALORES*/
.container-valores{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.container-valores .box-valor{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.ico__valor{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

.ico__valor--confianza{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-confianza.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__valor--pasion{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-pasion.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__valor--innovacion{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-innovacion.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__valor--integridad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-valor-integridad.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.ico__valor--excelencia{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-excelencia.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}




/*INTERNAS*/
.detalle nav{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.detalle .cenefa__interior{
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.detalle .cenefa__interior--servicios{
    background: url(../img/cenefas/servicios.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.detalle .cenefa__interior--corporativo{
    background: url(../img/cenefas/corporativo.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.detalle .cenefa__interior--socios{
    background: url(../img/cenefas/socios.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.detalle .cenefa__interior h2{
    text-align: center;
    color: #28b7e1;
    margin-top: 120px; 
}

.detalle .contenido{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.detalle .contenido h4 small{
    color: #7b89a2;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 140%;
}

.detalle .contenido p,
.detalle .contenido ul li{
    line-height: 170%;
}

.detalle .contenido .destacado{
    color: #7b89a2;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.detalle .contenido .bajada{
    color: #7b89a2;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.detalle .contenido ul{
    padding-left: 17px;
}

.detalle .medialuna{
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #efe9e9;
    margin-top: -100px; 
}

.detalle .thumb__ico{
    width: 160px;
    height: 140px;
    display: block;
    margin: -205px 0 0 57px;
    margin-top: -205px;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--gobernabilidad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-gobernabilidad.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--cyberseguridad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-cyberseguridad.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--sustentabilidad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-sustentabilidad.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--integridad{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-integridad.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--cyberacademia{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-cyberacademia.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 135%;
    object-fit: contain;

}

.detalle .thumb__ico--crisis{
    background: url(../img/iconos/ico-crisis.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.detalle .thumb__ico--cybertrust{
    background: url(../img/logos/Logo_Cybertrust_y_Center_01.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}


.detalle .img__socio1{
    display: block;
    margin: -205px 0 0 10px;    
    width: 240px;
    height: 507px;
}

.detalle .img__socio{
    display: block;
    /*margin: -205px 0 0 10px;*/
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    /*margin-top: -205px;*/
    width: 240px;
    height: 507px;
}

.menu-secundario{
    background: #e4dcdc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    clear: both;
}

.menu-secundario h5{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul li ul{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul li ul li{
    line-height: 120%;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul li ul li small{
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul li ul li:before{
    content: "+ ";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}

.detalle .contenido .menu-secundario ul li{
    line-height: 140%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.detalle .contenido .box.cv{
    display: none;
}

.detalle .contenido .box2.cv2{
    display: none;
}

.detalle .contenido .box3.cv3{
    display: none;
}

.detalle .contenido .tabs{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.detalle .contenido .tabs{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:  bold;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.detalle .contenido .tabs li{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: #acacac;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.detalle .contenido .tabs li.active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #1b4e96;
    color: #555;
}
```

Comment: You have no `.rows` in any of your divs. The bootstrap grid system works by putting columns inside of rows, inside of containers. You just have a lot of containers and columns here. No rows. That would definitely play a big part in not collapsing properly on smaller devices.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn`t notice that. However even now it has the row class div, the issue is still there...

Comment: Can you update your code with the row divs that you added?